# Submit form using jquery with specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, button

I am clicking a submit button using this:

**Hlml** :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>
```

**Js :**

```
$("#form_id").on('submit',(function(e) {
```

The problem is that I have more that 1 submit button on my **form wizard** so I need to target a specific submit button.

**LIke**

```
<button type="submit" id="submit_form" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>
```

How could I submit form using `id="submit_form` and `$("#form_id")` ?

Comment: *"The problem is that I have more that 1 submit button on my form wizard so I need to target a specific submit button."* Explain what a "form wizard" is. Why do you have more than one submit button?

Comment: please google, "jquery form wizard". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach click event to the button you want using the specific id attribute :

```
$("#form_id").on('click', '#submit_form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //You logic here

   //Submit form at the end if you want
   //$("#form_id").submit();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to be an answer that fixes a symptom, but ignores the disease of a poorly designed form.

Comment: In fact there's actually a ton of cases where the submit button could be needed more than ones.

Comment: bro, I have tried this but its not even submitting the form.

Comment: There could be, but we don't know if this is one of them.

Comment: @AnaGabriel have you uncommented `$("#form_id").submit();` ?

Comment: ** $("#form_id").on('submit', '#submit_form', (function(e) { **

Comment: It was a typo there check now please... https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/414/